# Swift mutating function struct pass struct’s variable name in function?

Tags: swift, struct, parameter-passing, mutating-function

I am working in Swift trying to update an organization struct that will need to hold a latitude and longitude. I created a mutating function in the struct that will update the latitude and longitude based on the organization organization struct’s address. I got it to work, but the issue is that when I call the mutating function, I need to manually enter the variable name with the .latitude and .longitude. Is there a way that I can pass the variable struct’s name automatically and reference the .latitude and .longitude without calling the specific variable name with it so I can make it more usable? I included an example below with my code. Thanks for your help!

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import CoreLocation

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

struct organization {
    var name: String
    var address: String
    var latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 0 //default setting for latitude
    var longitude: CLLocationDegrees = 0 //default setting for longitude
    
    mutating func getCoordinateFrom(completion: @escaping(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?, _ error: Error?) -> () ) {
        CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in
            completion(placemarks?.first?.location?.coordinate, error)
        }
    }
}

struct Coordinates {
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
}

//create an wildernessLodge variable of type organization
var wildernessLodge = organization(name: "Disney's Wilderness Lodge", address: "901 Timberline Dr, Orlando, FL 32830")

wildernessLodge.getCoordinateFrom { coordinate, error in
    guard let coordinate = coordinate, error == nil else { return }
    wildernessLodge.latitude = coordinate.latitude
    wildernessLodge.longitude = coordinate.longitude
    print("update 1 \(wildernessLodge)")
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Are you trying worried about the lines `wildernessLodge.latitude = coordinate.latitude` and `wildernessLodge.longitude = coordinate.longitude`?

Comment: `Coordinates` is exactly equivalent to the existing `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. Since you're already dependant on `CoreLocation` anyway, what's the point in this conversion?

Comment: Hi Alexander, yes the wilderness.latitude and wilderness.longitude are the lines I’m focusing on. Is there a way to say update the .latitude and .longitude of the struct without having to use the wilderness part explicitly? Since I’m passing the variable of type organization in the function, how can I do that with any variable of type organization struct without having to specifically reference the variable name?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your code. Why is `getCoordinateFrom` marked as `mutating`? Perhaps you meant to write something like this.

```swift
mutating func getCoordinatesFromAddress() {
    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in
        guard let coordinate = placemarks?.first?.location?.coordinate, error == nil else { return }
        self.latitude = coordinate.latitude
        self.longitude = coordinate.longitude
    }
}
```

Now this function is mutating (it modifies `self`), and

```swift
wildernessLodge.getCoordinateFrom { coordinate, error in ... }
```

can be replaced with

```swift
wildernessLodge.getCoordinatesFromAddress()
```

The only reason to leave the `getCoordinateFrom` method is if, somewhere in your code, you intend to get coordinates from an address but not update the coordinates in the struct. I can't imagine a good reason to do that, so I would recommend replacing the `getCoordinateFrom` method with something else.

Alternatively, if you generally intend to set the coordinates right after creating a value of this type, you might want to consider something like this.

```
init(name: String, address: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.address = address
    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in
        guard let coordinate = placemarks?.first?.location?.coordinate, error == nil else { return }
        self.latitude = coordinate.latitude
        self.longitude = coordinate.longitude
    }
}
```

or

```
init(name: String, address: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.address = address
    self.getCoordinatesFromAddress()
}
```

Then, you could create an `organization` using `organization(name: name, address: address)` and the coordinates would automatically be set correctly.

If neither of these are satisfactory, maybe you should create two different structs to capture the behavior you want.

```swift
struct Organization {
    var name: String
    var address: String
    func withCoordinates(completion: @escaping(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?, _ error: Error?) -> () ) {
        CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in
            completion(placemarks?.first?.location?.coordinate, error)
        }
    }
}
struct OrganizationWithCoordinates {
    var name: String
    var address: String
    var latitude: CLLocationDegrees
    var longitude: CLLocationDegrees
    init(from organization: Organization) {
        self.name = organization.name
        self.address = organization.address
        organization.withCoordinates { coordinate, error in
            guard let coordinate = coordinate, error == nil else { return }
            self.latitude = coordinate.latitude
            self.longitude = coordinate.longitude
        }
    }
}
```

I would prefer an approach like this, but I like having lots of types.

Finally, as noted in the comments, if you are really just concerned with brevity, you can replace

```swift
var latitude: CLLocationDegrees
var longitude: CLLocationDegrees
```

with

```swift
var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var latitude: CLLocationDegrees { coordinates.latitude }
var longitude: CLLocationDegrees { coordinates.longitude }
```

and then replace

```swift
wildernessLodge.latitude = coordinate.latitude
wildernessLodge.longitude = coordinate.longitude
```

with

```swift
wildernessLodge.coordinates = coordinate
```

In fact, you should feel free to combine any of these approaches.

Edit: As pointed out, these solutions do not work as-is. The fundamental tension is trying to work with `CLGeocoder`'s async method synchronously. One solution is to use a class instead of a struct. The other approach is to use a modification of the `withCoordinate` method above:

```swift
struct Organization {
    var name: String
    var address: String
    func withCoordinate(callback: @escaping (OrganizationWithCoordinate?, Error?) -> Void) {
        CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(self.address) { placemarks, error in
            if let coordinate = placemarks?.first?.location?.coordinate, error == nil {
                let orgWithCoord = OrganizationWithCoordinate(name: self.name, address: self.address, latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.latitude)
                callback(orgWithCoord, nil)
            } else {
                callback(nil, error)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
struct OrganizationWithCoordinate {
    var name: String
    var address: String
    var latitude: CLLocationDegrees
    var longitude: CLLocationDegrees
}

Organization(name: "Disney's Wilderness Lodge", address: "901 Timberline Dr, Orlando, FL 32830").withCoordinate { orgWithCoord, error in
    guard let orgWithCoord = orgWithCoord, error == nil else {
        print("Error")
        return
    }
    print(orgWithCoord)
}
```

This embraces the async nature of `CLGeocoder`.

Another solution could be to force `CLGeocoder` to be synchronous using `DispatchSemaphore` as follows. I don't think these work correctly in Playgrounds, but this should work in an actual app.

```swift
struct Organization {
    var name: String
    var address: String
    var latitude: CLLocationDegrees
    var longitude: CLLocationDegrees
    
    init(name: String, address: String) throws {
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        
        var tempCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
        var tempError: Error?
        
        let sema = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in
            tempCoordinate = placemarks?.first?.location?.coordinate
            tempError = error
            
            sema.signal()
        }
        // Warning: Will lock if called on DispatchQueue.main
        sema.wait()
        
        if let error = tempError {
            throw error
        }
        guard let coordinate = tempCoordinate else {
            throw NSError(domain: "Replace me", code: -1, userInfo: nil)
        }
        
        self.longitude = coordinate.longitude
        self.latitude = coordinate.latitude
    }
}

// Somewhere in your app
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Some queue")
queue.async {
    let wildernessLodge = try! Organization(name: "Disney's Wilderness Lodge", address: "901 Timberline Dr, Orlando, FL 32830")

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print(wildernessLodge)
    }
}
```

Here, a new queue to do `Organization` related work is created to avoid locking up the main queue. This method creates the least clunky-looking code in my opinion, but probably is not the most performant option. The location APIs are async for a reason.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response! The issue with these approaches is that you get a "escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter error and "self.latitude" captured by a closure before being initialized. That's why I had to use the function with a completion handler.

Comment: You're right. I forgot about this restriction when writing my answer. Very annoying! One solution would be to change your `struct` to a `class`. This will fix the error, but will also introduce reference semantics. If you take this route, you might want to make the setters of your variables private. I will edit my answer if this is satisfactory.

Comment: See my edit for an alternative solution as well.